# npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED en los framework

Tags: angular

cuando voy a intalar React, Angular u otro framework ya sea react, angula, etc. Me aparece el siguiente listado de errores:

```
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 2606:4700::6810:1822:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 2606:4700::6810:1822:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:501:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '2606:4700::6810:1822',
npm ERR!   port: 443,
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   requiredBy: '.'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\SENA\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-17T12_41_41_515Z-debug-0.log
```

se agradece cualquier respuesta. <3

Comment: You may want to look at [es.so] instead... Or [pt.so] if I've guessed wrong :).